# How to map the second highest value in each row of a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, probability-or-statistics, map

I have a matrix with three or more columns called `mat`. I would like to map the second highest value in each row of `mat` into its own list, and then take the mean of all the 2nd highest values. With only two rows, I managed to do this by using `Min`, like this:

```
h = Map[Min, mat];
Mean[h]
```

How can I achieve this with three or more rows? I have tried to use `RankedMin` and `RankedMax`, but could not get them to work with the `Map` function.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @Kuba I could not get this to work. When I try this on a matrix with two columns, it returns an error of the type `RankedMax::rvec: "Input {{0.757069},{0.211864}} is not a vector of reals or integers."`, and so on for each row in `mat`. In this example the first row is `{0.757069},{0.211864}`

Comment: @Kuba Yes, you are right. Is that important? To derive `mat` I used `Transpose` to cobine two other (single column) matrices

Comment: @Kuba You are right. I tested it by making a matrix without the `{}` around each value, and your suggestion then works. Do you know a way to turn a matrix with columns of lists with numerical values into a normal matrix with columns of numerical values? ...Other than doing it manually? Or put differently, how to cobine all the single-column lists that I have into a normal matrix with many columns (not columns of lists)?

Comment: @Kuba I ended up using `Flatten[]` on each list of values, and then `Transpose` to combine them into a many-column matrix. This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case this matters performance-wise you could also use `RankedMax` which is highly optimized for this purpose.

```
mat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10*6, 10000}];

Mean[RankedMax[#, 2] & /@ mat]
(* 0.999801 *)
```

For large matrices this is an order of magnitude faster.

```
In[34]:= AbsoluteTiming[r1 = Mean[RankedMax[#, 2] & /@ mat];]

Out[34]= {0.0151883, Null}

In[35]:= AbsoluteTiming[r2 = Mean[(Sort /@ mat)[[All, -2]]];]

Out[35]= {0.112088, Null}

In[36]:= r1 == r2

Out[36]= True
```

Comment: @kuba my apologies I didn't notice you had already posted this in the comments

Comment: No worries, thanks for the answer and comparison.

Comment: @AndyRoss Thank you. This works. I had problems using `RankedMax` initially because my matrix had lists with values in it,  for some reason, instead of just values. I managed to fix this by using `Flatten` on each column, before using transpose to make the final matrix. Afterwards I could use `RankedMax`

Answer (score 4):

This could be your matrix,

```
mat = RandomReal[2., {5, 5}]
(* {{0.124282, 0.382223, 1.49303, 0.869288, 1.44267}, {0.209928,
   0.065412, 0.694497, 1.49617, 1.31293}, {1.44424, 1.31737, 0.753354,
   0.460729, 1.0257}, {0.94123, 1.03758, 0.346167, 0.754396, 
  0.0348236}, {0.251986, 0.395477, 0.942587, 0.772752, 0.454348}} *)
```

To get a list of the second largest number of each row, first sort the rows

```
Sort /@ mat
(* {{0.124282, 0.382223, 0.869288, 1.44267, 1.49303}, {0.065412,
   0.209928, 0.694497, 1.31293, 1.49617}, {0.460729, 0.753354, 1.0257,
   1.31737, 1.44424}, {0.0348236, 0.346167, 0.754396, 0.94123, 
  1.03758}, {0.251986, 0.395477, 0.454348, 0.772752, 0.942587}} *)
```

Then take the second to last element of each row

```
(Sort /@ mat)[[All, -2]]
(* {1.44267, 1.31293, 1.31737, 0.94123, 0.772752} *)
```

And finally, take the `Mean`

```
Mean@(Sort /@ mat)[[All, -2]]
(* 1.15739 *)
```

Comment: This works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With Jason's data

```
list =
  {{0.124282, 0.382223, 1.49303, 0.869288, 1.44267},
   {0.209928, 0.065412, 0.694497, 1.49617, 1.31293},
   {1.44424, 1.31737, 0.753354, 0.460729, 1.0257},
   {0.94123, 1.03758, 0.346167, 0.754396, 0.0348236},
   {0.251986, 0.395477, 0.942587, 0.772752, 0.454348}};
```

Using the operator-form of `TakeLargest` (new in 10.1)

```
Last /@ TakeLargest[2] /@ list
```

{1.44267, 1.31293, 1.31737, 0.94123, 0.772752}

```
Mean[Last /@ TakeLargest[2] /@ list]
```

1.15739

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing the Jason's matrix and using `Nearest`:

```
 list =
  {{0.124282, 0.382223, 1.49303, 0.869288, 1.44267},
   {0.209928, 0.065412, 0.694497, 1.49617, 1.31293},
   {1.44424, 1.31737, 0.753354, 0.460729, 1.0257},
   {0.94123, 1.03758, 0.346167, 0.754396, 0.0348236},
   {0.251986, 0.395477, 0.942587, 0.772752, 0.454348}};

  f[vec_?VectorQ] := Last@Nearest[vec, Max@vec, 2]
  f[mat_?MatrixQ] := Map[f@# &, mat]

  f@list

  (*{1.44267, 1.31293, 1.31737, 0.94123, 0.772752}*)

  Mean@f@list

  (*1.15739*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = {{0.124282, 0.382223, 1.49303, 0.869288, 1.44267}, {0.209928, 
    0.065412, 0.694497, 1.49617, 1.31293}, {1.44424, 1.31737, 
    0.753354, 0.460729, 1.0257}, {0.94123, 1.03758, 0.346167, 
    0.754396, 0.0348236}, {0.251986, 0.395477, 0.942587, 0.772752, 
    0.454348}}; (* Thanks to @JasonB *)

Last@MaximalBy[#, Identity, 2] & /@ list // Mean
```

OR

```
pos = List /@ (First@Ordering[#, -2] & /@ list)
MapThread[Extract, {list, pos}] // Mean
```

---

*Result:*

> 1.15739